# Receiving data from stream continuously and reading stream

Tags: c

I'm receiving string and save it into input buffer. This is stream and string could be incomplete, so I'm looking for the last STOP - string, copy the rest (which is a begin of the next block) and append the  data from the next delivery behind the copied data.
In-between I do some operations on the input buffer(like memcpy). Should I make a copy of input buffer or can I use the input_buffer, which I have?

Some people told me, that this would make no sense:

```
 if ( bytes_received == 0 ) {
      continue;
    }
```

But this is stream. If this makes no sense, how can I assure, that I will continuously receive data?

```
char * strrstr(char *string, char *find, ssize_t len)
{

  char *cp;    
  for (cp = string + strlen(string) - 4; cp >= string; cp--)
  {
    if (strncmp(cp, find, 4) == 0)
    return cp+4;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main ( void ) {
  char * input_buffer = malloc(MAXLENGTH);
  size_t restSize=0;
  char * restP;

  int socket_handle = reqData(subStr);
  ssize_t bytes_received ;
  for (;;) {

    bytes_received = recv ( socket_handle , input_buffer+restSize ,MAXLENGTH-1, 0 ) ;

    input_buffer[bytes_received-1] = '\0';
    if ( bytes_received == -1 ) {
      printf ( "-1 An error occured during the receive procedure \n" ) ;
      return 0 ;
    }
    if ( bytes_received == 0 ) {
      printf ( "0 An error occured during the receive procedure \n" ) ;
      return 0 ;
    }
    restP = strrstr (input_buffer, STOP, 4);
    if (restP == NULL)
    {
      restSize = 0;
      continue;
    }
    restSize = strlen(restP);//MAXLENGTH - (restP - input_buffer) + 1;
    processXML(input_buffer, restP, t);
    strcpy(input_buffer,  restP);

  }
  close(socket_handle);
  free (input_buffer);
  return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes in your code:

1. Here: `input_buffer[bytes_received-1] = '\0';` you do not check if bytes_recived is -1 (you do later). Also, you have to check if it is 0, because a negative index for an array is not allowed. Yo do this later too, so just move the quoted line.
2. Consider using strstr function from string.h instead of strrstr. Even if your implementation seems fine (and it is a good exercise, if that is its purpose), it is recommanded to use standard functions, as they are safer than your implemenation, which may hide some bugs for example.
3. When calling recv function, there is no need to expect MAXLENGTH-1. MAXLENGTH will work too.

Now, to answer your question, this might be useful: [recv() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526382/recv-returns-0)
As you see, when recv returns 0, there is no point in expecting input anymore.